# Silverlight - Catching a click of an item underneath another

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, c#-3.0

I've got a silverlight app. The app draws an image, then on top of the image is a mostly transparent ellipse. The ellipse is there for display purposes only.

I had thought I read somewhere that mouseLeftButtonDown events would fire on all objects that are wired up to it, regardless of z-order and if something else was sitting on top of it.  I could be totally wrong (and based on my tests I am) -

So is there anyway to get the ellipse to NOT catch the event so that the other object underneath it can catch it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I found the solution.  I need to set the IsHitTestVisible property to false, then it ignores clicks.

Comment: As you said, MouseLeftButtonDown fires on any(not all) object that is directly hit by a click. However only the highest one will take that event unless IsHitTestVisible is false or you manually pass that event up.